# AsyncTask Image Compression - FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3 (Upload to Firebase Storage Later))

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask, firebase-storage, image-compression

I am trying to compress images in a background thread using this class ...

```
public class BackgroundImageResize extends AsyncTask<Uri, Integer, byte[]>{

    Bitmap mBitmap;

    public BackgroundImageResize(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(bitmap != null){
            this.mBitmap = bitmap;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(NextActivity.this, "compressing image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected byte[] doInBackground(Uri... params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: started.");

        if(mBitmap == null){
            try{
                mBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(NextActivity.this.getContentResolver(), params[0]);
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e)
            {

            }
        }
        byte[] bytes = null;
        bytes = getBytesFromBitmap(mBitmap, 100);
        return bytes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(byte[] bytes) {
        super.onPostExecute(bytes);
        mUploadBytes = bytes;

        //execute the upload task


    }
}

public static byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int quality){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality,stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

passing bitmap to constructor like

```
BackgroundImageResize backgroundImageResize = new BackgroundImageResize(bitmap);
```

and calling the execute() method in onClickListener like

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating to the final share screen.");

            //Compress the image

             backgroundImageResize.execute();
```

and I'm getting this FATAL EXCEPTION error

```
4-27 00:10:01.318 17091-18093/manika.aditya.ekayana E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
                                                                   Process: manika.aditya.ekayana, PID: 17091
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                                                                       at manika.aditya.ekayana.Share.NextActivity$BackgroundImageResize.doInBackground(NextActivity.java:158)
                                                                       at manika.aditya.ekayana.Share.NextActivity$BackgroundImageResize.doInBackground(NextActivity.java:135)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
```

whenever I run the app and click on the textView 
I don't understand what's causing it...

I have to upload the compressed image to Firebase Storage later

this is the upload method, just in case

```
public void uploadNewPhoto(String photoType, final String caption,final int count, final String imgUrl,
                       Bitmap bm){
Log.d(TAG, "uploadNewPhoto: attempting to uplaod new photo.");

FilePaths filePaths = new FilePaths();
//case1) new photo
if(photoType.equals(mContext.getString(R.string.new_photo))){
    Log.d(TAG, "uploadNewPhoto: uploading NEW photo.");

    String user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    StorageReference storageReference = mStorageReference
            .child(filePaths.FIREBASE_IMAGE_STORAGE + "/" + user_id + "/photo" + (count + 1));

    //convert image url to bitmap
    if(bm == null){
        bm = ImageManager.getBitmap(imgUrl);
    }

    byte[] bytes = ImageManager.getBytesFromBitmap(bm, 90);


    UploadTask uploadTask = null;
    uploadTask = storageReference.putBytes(bytes);

    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Uri firebaseUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

            Toast.makeText(mContext, "photo upload success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //add the new photo to 'photos' node and 'user_photos' node
            addPhotoToDatabase(caption, firebaseUrl.toString());

            //navigate to the main feed so the user can see their photo
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, HomeActivity.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Photo upload failed.");
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Photo upload failed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            double progress = (100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();

            if(progress - 15 > mPhotoUploadProgress){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "photo upload progress: " + String.format("%.0f", progress) + "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mPhotoUploadProgress = progress;
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "onProgress: upload progress: " + progress + "% done");
        }
    });
```

I know the answer might be really obvious but I'm a beginner ... Thank You in advance :)

this is how I call the upload method, by the way

```
                //upload the image to firebase

            Toast.makeText(NextActivity.this, "Attempting to upload new photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String caption = mCaption.getText().toString();

            if(intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image))){
                imgUrl = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image));
                mFirebaseMethods.uploadNewPhoto(getString(R.string.new_photo), caption, imageCount, imgUrl,null);
            }
            else if(intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.selected_bitmap))){
                bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra(getString(R.string.selected_bitmap));
                mFirebaseMethods.uploadNewPhoto(getString(R.string.new_photo), caption, imageCount, null,bitmap);
            }
```

in the onClickViewListener

:P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your Log the problem is

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
```

I believe, this is caused by `param[0]` in the line

```
mBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(NextActivity.this.getContentResolver(), params[0]);
```

`params[]` must be `null`, because in `onClick()` you call `backgroundImageResize.execute()` without an argument, which would be passed to `doInBackground()` and stored in `param[]`.

**As a solution** you just have to pass a Uri to `backgroundImageResize.execute()` in your `onClick()` like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ...
    backgroundImageResize.execute(myUri);
    ...
}
```

**Another way** would be to avoid your app to be crashing by catching the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in `doInBackground()` like this:

```
if(mBitmap == null){
    try{
        mBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(NextActivity.this.getContentResolver(), params[0]);
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {}
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExeption aioobe) {}
}
```

Comment: One last annoying question :P I passed the image URI as parameter in `backgroundImageResize.execute(imageUri);` but now I'm getting this error `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getByteCount() on a null object reference`  because I'm using getByteCount() function to log the image size, before and after compression `Log.d(TAG, "size before compression " + mBitmap.getByteCount() / 1000000);
            bytes = getBytesFromBitmap(mBitmap, 100);
            Log.d(TAG, "size after compression " + bytes.length / 1000000); `

Comment: Seems like `mBitmap` is `null`. My guess is, that the Uri is not correct, and therefore `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap()` returns `null`.   To avoid your app from crashing, you can put `bytes = getBytesFromBitmap(mBitmap, 100);` in a try-catch-block or in an if-statement, where you check, if `mBitmap` is `null`

Comment: this is how I am retrieving the Uri `imgUrl = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image));
                    imageUri = Uri.parse(imgUrl) ;` don't worry about the getStringExtra() that is just for passing caption of the image. Is it the correct way ? I have been retrieving the Url with getString() method without problems throughout my project. Thanks in advance, you're amazing :)

Comment: Yes, you can do it like that. But what I meant was: Is the uri, that you are passing, correct itself. I mean, is there really an image file existing at the location specified by the url? You should check that.

Comment: Another thing: Following questions, that doesn't really have something to do with the topic question shouldn't asked in a comment. You better ask a **new** question at stackoverflow.

Comment: this is what I did `imgUrl = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image));
                Log.d(TAG, "Image URL" + imgUrl);
                    imageUri = Uri.parse(imgUrl) ;
                Log.d(TAG, "Image URI" + imageUri);` and this is the log for the Uri `04-27 18:53:49.458 25967-25967/manika.aditya.ekayana D/NextActivity: Image URI/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/IMG_20171220_185159_236.jpg` there is an image at the location... I'm so tired XD

Comment: Dude, ask a new question :D You will get more response!! Sadly I have no idea, sorry

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063695/converting-url-to-uri-and-passing-it-to-asynctask here :)