# Converting Url to Uri and passing it to AsyncTask<>

Tags: android, image, android-asynctask, uri

I am converting a Url to Uri in the following way

```
imgUrl = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image));
            Log.d(TAG, "Image URL" + imgUrl);
                imageUri = Uri.parse(imgUrl) ;
            Log.d(TAG, "Image URI" + imageUri);
```

then passing it to this function

```
 BackgroundImageResize backgroundImageResize = new BackgroundImageResize(bitmap);
           backgroundImageResize.execute(imageUri);
```

and BackgroundImageResize takes arguments as

```
public class BackgroundImageResize extends AsyncTask<Uri, Integer, byte[]>
```

now this method

```
Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: megabytes before compression: " + mBitmap.getByteCount() / 1000000 );
        bytes = getBytesFromBitmap(mBitmap, 100);
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: megabytes before compression: " + bytes.length / 1000000 );
```

is returning this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getByteCount()' on a null object reference
```

in previous discussions with a really smart person, it has been concluded that, maybe, the Uri is incorrect

**How do I pass the correct Uri ?**

this is the doInBackground() just in case

```
@Override
    protected byte[] doInBackground(Uri... params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: started.");

        if(mBitmap == null){
            try{
                mBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(NextActivity.this.getContentResolver(), params[0]);
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        byte[] bytes = null;
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: megabytes before compression: " + mBitmap.getByteCount() / 1000000 );
        bytes = getBytesFromBitmap(mBitmap, 100);
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: megabytes before compression: " + bytes.length / 1000000 );
        return bytes;
    }
```

I suspect that this line of code

```
mBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(NextActivity.this.getContentResolver(), params[0]);
```

is not doing it's job :P

Comment: if(mBitmap!= null) use this

Comment: you are getting correct image url ? please mention how you are fetching image url.

Comment: `imgUrl = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image));` intent is initialized beforehand and is the object of `import android.content.Intent; ` here's the log of an example image `Log.d(TAG, "Image URL" + imgUrl);` prints `04-27 20:08:09.333 4740-4740/manika.aditya.ekayana D/NextActivity: Image URL/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/WallChastic/Wallpaper-9693.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the 2 Logs with the ++++++++++++ lines in your doInBackGround() and post your Logcat:

```
@Override
protected byte[] doInBackground(Uri... params) {
    Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: started.");

    Log.d(TAG, "+++++++++++++ params[0]: " + params[0]);

    if(mBitmap == null){
        try{
            mBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(NextActivity.this.getContentResolver(), params[0]);
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "+++++++++++++ mBitmap: " + mBitmap);

    byte[] bytes = null;
    Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: megabytes before compression: " + mBitmap.getByteCount() / 1000000 );
    bytes = getBytesFromBitmap(mBitmap, 100);
    Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: megabytes before compression: " + bytes.length / 1000000 );
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: `Log.d(TAG, "+++++++++++++ params[0]: " + params[0]);` ------ `04-27 21:39:50.996 18164-18701/manika.aditya.ekayana D/NextActivity: +++++++++++++ params[0]: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/IMG_20171226_172351_047.jpg`                   ` Log.d(TAG, "+++++++++++++ mBitmap: " + mBitmap);` ------  `04-27 21:39:50.996 18164-18701/manika.aditya.ekayana D/NextActivity: +++++++++++++ mBitmap: null
`

Comment: Yeah, as I thought, mBitmap is null. So, either the file really does not exist at that location, or you don't have permission to access it. Try to add  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`  to your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: already have added the permission... how is mBitmap still null, if params[0] has been initialized with the correct path :/ ...

Answer (score 1):

So as it turns out, Locdoc01 was right all along, the Uri was wrong, all I had to do was append file:// to the url before parsing it into Uri ...

like this

```
imgUrl = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image));
ImgUrlAppended = "file://" + imgUrl;
Log.d(TAG, "Image URL" + imgUrl);
imageUri = Uri.parse(ImgUrlAppended) ;
Log.d(TAG, "Image URI" + imageUri);
```

Image compresses now !

thank you for all the support, StackOverflow !
hope this helps someone

Comment: If Locdoc01’s answer was helpful, don’t forget to upvote it.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it ;)